# POST 404 (Not Found) error while trying to write to http://localhost:3000/messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm trying to build a basic website with client-server interaction via node js.
I have a near paradoxical issue where on one hand, going to `http://localhost:3000/messages` will show me the needed data

**I know that there are other potential issues with the code. I will start working on them once I get past that odd 404 error**

[http://localhost:3000/messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afM2d.png)

> [{"name":"Jim","message":"heyo"},{"name":"Johny","message":"Yo"}]

but when trying to add more data to it via

`$.post('http://localhost:3000/messages', messages)`

while messages containing the data from two input fields (I was able to add data through those fields only on client side), pressing the button with the proper event listener yielded the following error in the console
`POST http://localhost:3000/messages 404 (Not Found)            jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2`

(the jquery part is at the far-right side of the console frame).

The weirdest part is, that in the network tab of the dev window, two instances of http://localhost:3000/messages appear, while the second one marked as an error

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1IF0.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg0Lc.png)

here is the entire code, since I'm not sure what else might be important in my situation

**HTML, CSS & JS, file name - index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Send Message</h1>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="name" id="name">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="message" id="message">
        <button id="send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div id="messages"></div>
</div>
<script>

    $('#send').click(()=>{
        var messages = {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            message: $('#message').val()
        }
        hostMessage(messages)});
    $(document).ready(()=>{
        displayMessages();
        console.log("The page has finished loading");
    })
    function addMessage(message){
        $('#messages').append(`<h1>${message.name}</h1><h4>${message.message}`);
    }
    function displayMessages(){
        $.get('http://localhost:3000/messages', (data)=>{
            data.forEach(element=> {
                addMessage(element)
            }, this);
            
        })
    }
    function hostMessage(messages){
        $.post('http://localhost:3000/messages', messages) 

    }
</script>
```

**NODE JS, serverside code, file name server.js**

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var messages = [
    {name: "Jim", message: "heyo"},
    {name: "Johny", message: "Yo"}
]

app.get('/messages', (req, res)=>{
    res.send((messages))
})
app.post('messages', (req, res)=>{
    messages.push(req.body)
    console.log(req.body)
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
var server = app.listen(3000,()=> {
    console.log('Server is listening through port ', server.address().port);
});
```

Sorry if it's a bit messy, I'm still very much new to this whole thing.

Comment: can you add ```/``` to ```app.post('messages'...```, like```'/messages'```

Comment: changed it to app.post('/messages', (req, res)=>{
    messages.push(req.body)
    console.log(req.body)
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
still same error sadly

Comment: does it work now?

Comment: You mean having css customization? I imported some predefined classes (designs for various elements) from https://getbootstrap.com/
not sure if that's what you meant, though 
(oh, I see that that comment was deleted)